# Run a function on document.ready and onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, document-ready

Is there a way to make this ajax-response run on document.ready, AND onClik without copy/paste the code in another function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ads = $('#ads').val();
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "./services/finn_bilder.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ads: ads},
        success:function(data){
            $('#AdsDiv').html(data);
        }
```

I want this to run onClick $('#id').click(function()); and the way its working now, without copy/paste?

Comment: What's wrong with using another _named_ function, and calling it both in `.click` and in `.ready`? That's the only sane approach

Comment: There's always `$(document).on('ready click', ajax);` but there are issues with `.on('ready')`

Comment: Make sure to see the differences between the answers: *var ads = $('#ads').val();* is ran only once in the example LightStyle gave, I made sure it will accure every time the ajax funciton is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it inside document ready and bind it to document.click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ads = $('#ads').val();
    function ajax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "./services/finn_bilder.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{ads: ads},
            success:function(data){
                $('#AdsDiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    ajax();
    $(document).click(function() {
        ajax();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you can reuse the javascript function you've created:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Will occur at document load
    ajax();
    // Will occur at every click
    $(document).click(function() { ajax(); });
}

function ajax(){
    var ads = $('#ads').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "./services/finn_bilder.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ads: ads},
        success:function(data){
            $('#AdsDiv').html(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: `$(document).click(function() { ajax(); });` could probably be shortened to `$(document).click(ajax);`

Comment: Indeed. As long as the "ajax" function doesn'doesn't accept any arguments. Runs under any condition and it's return value is ignored (much like the example above).